# Ruby factorial function

Tags: ruby, math, factorial

I'm going crazy: Where is the Ruby function for factorial? No, I don't need tutorial implementations, I just want the function from the library. It's not in Math!

I'm starting to doubt, is it a standard library function?

Comment: I do it like `6.downto(1).inject(:*)`

Comment: @mckeed: Or `(1..6).inject(:*)` which is a bit more succinct.

Comment: @sepp2k: sure, but I prefer to have the number I am "acting on" out front for readability

Comment: why would you expect there to be one?

Comment: I wonder what the status is of mathematics and science libraries for Ruby.

Comment: Just a note on the provided examples using inject. `(1..num).inject(:*)` fails for the case where `num == 0`. `(1..(num.zero? ? 1 : num)).inject(:*)` gives the correct answer for the 0 case and returns `nil` for negative parameters.

Comment: @mckeed The `n.downto(1).inject(:*)` should be the answer (if you remember to account for 0)

Comment: @GregS, why wouldn't you expect there to be one?  It is the Ruby standard Math library after all.  A bit sad really...

Comment: Math? Bah! Not in Ruby!

Answer (score 140, accepted):

There is no factorial function in the standard library.

Comment: Ruby has the `Math.gamma` method, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352690/407213

Comment: What a crazy logic! We have (n-1)! function and don't have plain n! !!!

Answer (score 121):

Like this is better

```
(1..n).inject(:*) || 1
```

Comment: Or specify the initial value directly: `(1..n).reduce(1, :*)`.

Answer (score 77):

It's not in the standard library but you can extend the Integer class.

```
class Integer
  def factorial_recursive
    self <= 1 ? 1 : self * (self - 1).factorial_recursive
  end
  def factorial_iterative
    f = 1; for i in 1..self; f *= i; end; f
  end
  alias :factorial :factorial_iterative
end
```

N.B. Iterative factorial is a better choice for obvious performance reasons.

Comment: He explicitly said, he doesn't want an implementation.

Comment: He may not; but people searching SO for "Ruby factorial" might.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factorial#Ruby is just wrong. There isn't a case for 0

Comment: Is the recursive version actually slower? It might depend on whether Ruby does tail-recursive optimization.

Comment: I don't believe the recursive version is actually recursive. It calls `factorial`, which is aliased to `factorial_iterative`. It never recurses into itself. So it's indirectly iterative.

Answer (score 29):

Shamelessly cribbed from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factorial#Ruby, my personal favorite is

```
class Integer
  def fact
    (1..self).reduce(:*) || 1
  end
end

>> 400.fact
=> 64034522846623895262347970319503005850702583026002959458684445942802397169186831436278478647463264676294350575035856810848298162883517435228961988646802997937341654150838162426461942352307046244325015114448670890662773914918117331955996440709549671345290477020322434911210797593280795101545372667251627877890009349763765710326350331533965349868386831339352024373788157786791506311858702618270169819740062983025308591298346162272304558339520759611505302236086810433297255194852674432232438669948422404232599805551610635942376961399231917134063858996537970147827206606320217379472010321356624613809077942304597360699567595836096158715129913822286578579549361617654480453222007825818400848436415591229454275384803558374518022675900061399560145595206127211192918105032491008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This implementation also happens to be the fastest among the variants listed in Rosetta Code.

### update #1

Added `|| 1` to handle the zero case.

### update #2

With thanks and appreciation to [Mark Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182590/mark-thomas), here's a version that is a bit more efficient, elegant and obscure:

```
class Integer
  def fact
    (2..self).reduce(1,:*)
  end
end
```

Comment: what the heck does that mean?! yeah it's fast but its very unuserfriendly though

Comment: it's also incorrect for 0! - should be something like: if self <= 1; 1; else; (1..self).reduce(:*); end

Comment: @allen - Don't blame the language if you can't understand it.  It simply means, take the range 1 to self, then remove the first element (1) from it (i.e. that's what reduce means in functional programming).  Then remove the first element of what's left (2) and multiply (:*) those together.  Now remove the first element from what's left (3) and multiply that with the running total. Keep going until there's nothing left (i.e. you've handled the entire range).  If reduce fails (because the array is empty in the case of 0!) then just return 1 anyway.

Comment: You can also handle the zero case by specifying the initial value in `reduce`: `(1..self).reduce(1,:*)`.

Comment: Actually you can use `(2..self).reduce(1,:*)`, if micro-efficiency is your thing :)

Answer (score 21):

In math, `factorial of n` is just the `gamma function of n+1` 

(see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Ruby has `Math.gamma()` so just use `Math.gamma(n+1)` and cast it back to an integer if desired.

Comment: That's crazy :D this should be the solution.

Answer (score 14):

You could also use [`Math.gamma`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html#method-c-gamma) function which boils down to factorial for integer parameters.

Comment: From the docs: "Note that gamma(n) is same as fact(n-1) for integer n > 0. However gamma(n) returns float and can be an approximation". If one takes that into account, it works, but the reduce solution seems a  lot more straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for this! My gut says to use towards the standard library over a custom-written reduce whenever possible. Profiling might suggest otherwise.

Comment: Note: It's O(1) and precise for `0..22`: MRI Ruby actually performs a lookup  for those values (see `static const double fact_table[]` in the [source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Math.html#method-c-lgamma)). Beyond that, its an approximation. 23!, for instance, requires a 56-bit mantissa which is impossible to represent precisely using he IEEE 754 double which has a 53-bit mantissas.

Answer (score 14):

```
class Integer
  def !
    (1..self).inject(:*)
  end
end
```

#### examples

```
!3  # => 6
!4  # => 24
```

Comment: What’s wrong with `class Integer ; def ! ; (1..self).inject(:*) ; end ; end`?

Comment: @mudasobwa I like it, I have refactored for simplicity.

Comment: I'd respectfully suggest that overriding an [instance method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) incorporated into all Ruby objects to return a truthy value, rather than a falsy one may not make you many friends.

Comment: It might be really dangerous to make the negate operator to become something else when `a` happens to be `Integer` in the case of `!a`... doing so may cause a bug to exist which is very hard to tell. If `a` happens to be a big number such as `357264543` then the processor is going into a big loop and people may wonder why the program all of a sudden becomes slow

Comment: This answer was more just a cool thing to share rather than a practical example to use.

Answer (score 9):

I would do

```
(1..n).inject(1, :*)
```

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote my own:

```
def fact(n)
  if n<= 1
    1
  else
    n * fact( n - 1 )
  end
end
```

Also, you can define a falling factorial:

```
def fall_fact(n,k)
  if k <= 0
    1
  else
    n*fall_fact(n - 1, k - 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

With high respect to all who participated and spent their time to help us, I would like to share my benchmarks of the solutions listed here.
Params:

iterations = 1000

n = 6

```
                                     user     system      total        real
Math.gamma(n+1)                   0.000383   0.000106   0.000489 (  0.000487)
(1..n).inject(:*) || 1            0.003986   0.000000   0.003986 (  0.003987)
(1..n).reduce(1, :*)              0.003926   0.000000   0.003926 (  0.004023)
1.upto(n) {|x| factorial *= x }   0.003748   0.011734   0.015482 (  0.022795)
```

For n = 10

```
  user     system      total        real
0.000378   0.000102   0.000480 (  0.000477)
0.004469   0.000007   0.004476 (  0.004491)
0.004532   0.000024   0.004556 (  0.005119)
0.027720   0.011211   0.038931 (  0.058309)
```

Comment: Worth noting that the fastest one `Math.gamma(n+1)` is also only approximate for n > 22, so may not be suitable for all use cases.

Answer (score 4):

#### Just call this function

```
def factorial(n=0)
  (1..n).inject(:*)
end
```

#### examples

```
factorial(3)
factorial(11)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Math.gamma.floor` is an easy way to produce an approximation and then round it back down to the correct integer result. Should work for all Integers, include an input check if necessary.

Comment: Correction: After `n = 22` it ceases to give an exact answer and produces approximations.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do it, although it really isn't necessary.

```
class Factorial
   attr_reader :num
   def initialize(num)
      @num = num
   end

   def find_factorial
      (1..num).inject(:*) || 1
   end
end

number = Factorial.new(8).find_factorial
puts number
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find a Ruby [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9528) useful. It contains a nontrivial [patch](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/download/4855/the_code.rb) that includes a [demo Bash script](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/download/4856/run_demo.bash). The speed difference between a naive loop and the solution presented in the batch can be literally 100x (hundred fold). Written all in pure Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version seems to be clear to me even though it's not as clean.

```
def factorial(num)
    step = 0
    (num - 1).times do (step += 1 ;num *= step) end
    return num
end
```

This was my irb testing line that showed each step.

```
num = 8;step = 0;(num - 1).times do (step += 1 ;num *= step; puts num) end;num
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would the standard library require a factorial method, when there is a built-in iterator for this exact purpose? It is called `upto`.

No you do not need to use recursion, like all these other answers show.

```
def fact(n)
  n == 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1)
end
```

Rather, the built-in iterator upto can be used to calculate factorials:

```
factorial = 1
1.upto(10) {|x| factorial *= x }
factorial
 => 3628800
```

Comment: I like it but it's useful up to 50,000; anything higher is not a match for.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Integer
  def factorial
    return self < 0 ? false : self==0 ? 1 : self.downto(1).inject(:*)
    #Not sure what other libraries say, but my understanding is that factorial of 
    #anything less than 0 does not exist.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another way (=

```
def factorial(number)
  number = number.to_i
  number_range = (number).downto(1).to_a
  factorial = number_range.inject(:*)
  puts "The factorial of #{number} is #{factorial}"
end
factorial(#number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way to do it:

```
# fact(n) => Computes the Factorial of "n" = n!

def fact(n) (1..n).inject(1) {|r,i| r*i }end

fact(6) => 720
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby **standard library function for factorial** is not available. We can make a simple function of factorial in ruby in this way.

```
def factorial_number(n)
 if n <= 1
    1
 else
    n * factorial_number(n-1)
  end
end

puts factorial_number(6) #Output is 720   => (6*5*4*3*2*1)
puts factorial_number(8) #Output is 40320 => (8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1)
```

Comment: Outputs `0` when tried with `5`

Comment: Oh nevermind it worked with a fix

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt It worked with a fix. when we try any number in factorail_number(n). like factorial_number(5). Return 120

Comment: I replaced all `1` and `<=` but it returned 0 when tried with any number

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt Do you use:- puts factorial_number(5)? and getting 0.?